# Repair a file using Audacity?

Tags: audio-editing, audacity

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the attached audio clip between 9 to 18 seconds. When I listen using my headphone/headset or laptop speakers, they sort of vibrate very rapidly/loudly (hard to describe) and ruins the whole experience.

[Link to file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/fnxw8s27nqwwxvc/1.wav/file)

Also it would be great if someone could tell be how to correct this using Audacity. I tried using deamplifying with clipping, low pass filter, and compression. Low pass filter gave some improvement on headset, but on the laptop it sounds the same as original.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was recorded too loud and is clipping heavily. The top's been chopped off the waveform (see picture).  The information above that 'brick wall' is lost.   If there's just an occasional clipped peak, restoration software can sometimes make an intelligent guess at the lost information. But there isn't really a fix for this degree of distortion, particularly for 'acoustic' music like this.   Re-record, and turn the input level down.

[image]

Comment: Yep. As always, the rule is, there is no algorithm, tool, software, equipment, or any other gadget that can magically construct information that wasn't recorded to begin with. This isn't CSI, you can't just ask a lab tech to "enhance", and they will turn a single pixel into a high-resolution image of the license plate.

Comment: @JörgWMittag There are "clipping restoration" algorithms that do a good job with occasional clipping in recordings where the peaks are a few dB above the maximum level, and they do "magically" reconstruct the peaks of the waveforms based on the audio around it. But this particular recording is just clipped too much. Also, the recording device seems to have had a limiter switched on that tried to squash the peaks, which makes it even harder to restore the clipped parts.

Comment: It seems to have suffered from the ultimate 'limiter',   an attempt to record over 0db :-)